# Printing correct number of decimal points using %f c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print a number up to say 5 decimal places.

I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a = 987.65;
    float b = 1.23456789;
    scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
    printf("%.5f %.5f", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the result as 987.65000 and 1.23456 
I want the result to be 987.65 and 1.23456, so basically I want up to 5 i.e <=5 decimal digits in my answer.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want with just `printf`. One possible solution is to use `snprintf` to get the full value and then manually chop off extra digits that you don't want.

Comment: Did you try `printf("%6f %6f", a, b)`? It's not exactly what you want, but maybe it's close.

Comment: @kaylum You can do it, see my answer.

Comment: @space_voyager Nice

Answer (score 4):

A slightly less technical way to do it would be using `setprecision`, as displayed below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a = 987.65;
    float b = 1.23456789;

    cout << setprecision(5);
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
987.65 1.2346
```

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that a computer can't exactly represent most floating point numbers.

Also, you want a complex formatting rule:  *if ending digits are zero, print spaces*.

The problem is that your number 987.65000 could be represented as 98.6500001 and so wouldn't work with your formatting rule.

I believe you will have to write your own formatting function to achieve the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that does what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

unsigned int numPlaces = 5; //number of decimal places

unsigned int determinePlaces (float number) {
    unsigned int myPlaces = 0;
    while (number != (int)(number) && myPlaces<=numPlaces-1) {
        number = number*10;
        myPlaces++;
    }
    return myPlaces;
}

int main() {
    float a = 987.65;
    float b = 1.23456789;

    printf("%.*f %.*f\n", determinePlaces(a), a, determinePlaces(b), b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
987.65 1.23457
```

Basically, the code keeps on multiplying the goat by 10 until the cast to an integer (essentially taking the floor value) matches the float. If it doesn't when it reaches the fifth multiplication by 10, we satisfy ourselves with a `printf` of 5 decimal places. Otherwise, we print the amount that was necessary to make the match to the floor value.

Comment: This will fail for certain numbers leaving trailing zeroes or removing digits when it shouldn't.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Any number which when multiplied by 10 repeatedly, will change the value of one or more of its decimal digits. This will happen for some because floating points cannot represent values exactly.

Comment: Give an example... I don't know what you mean.

Comment: On a side note, passing a floating value to this function, that is greater than INT_MAX, will cause undefined behavior when it is explicitly converted to int.

Comment: Do you mean I should change to `long int` or something larger?

Comment: Hi. I have found an example: `0.50000005960464478f` which causes incorrect results. The result should be either 1 or 17, but your function returns 4

Comment: Here is another one: `1000000.125f`, should return 3 but it returns 1.